# Recovering files after processing

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

Before the October eve, the information provided in the Revit console log allowed us to recover the return files.
Now this is not possible anymore!

Before:

```
  "outputFile": {
    "optional": true,
    "localName": "OutputRvtFile.rvt",
    "url": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/caqg5kf4prwtqmmvrw_designautomation/objects/20190718115854_output_xxxxxxx.rvt",
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": "Bearer eyJh…."
    },
    "verb": "put"
  },
```

Now :

```
"outputFile": {
    "optional": true,
    "localName": "OutputRvtFile.rvt",
    "url": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/Masked:tAUm....1RT08=",
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": "Masked:MT….E+zJONm3VU="
    },
    "verb": "put"
  },
```

Before we had the file link as well as the varible Bearer but now there is more and the documentation has not been updated, or not found the latest news.

When I donwload the file, I have this element :
{ "developerMessage":"The requested resource does not exist.","userMessage":"","errorCode":"ERR-002","more info":"http://developer.api.autodesk.com/documentation/v1/errors/err-002"}

Could someone put me on the right road?
What is my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Olivier,

The RVT output file's URL and authorization headers are the same URL and authorization headers you passed into Design Automation for Revit as part of your WorkItem payload.

Autodesk values your privacy and the security of your data in Design Automation.  Your URLs and bearer tokens are being masked in Design Automation logs, including report.log, so that your sensitive data is not visible to Autodesk after your job is run.

Best,
Michael